# How can I use .mousemove to fade a background image according to distance from center page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, trigonometry

I have this function set up

```
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
 var winW = window.innerWidth;
 }

var xM = winW/180; 

var axis = 0;
$(window).bind('mousemove',function(e){
 var xCoord =  Math.floor(e.pageX/xM);
 axis = 0.6 * Math.sin(xCoord);
 var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + ", " + xCoord + " )";
     $("span#showme").text(pageCoords);
 });
    setInterval(function() {
     $("#welcome-background").fadeTo(0, 0.4 + axis);
 }, 100);
```

(for additional reference and working visual- http://jsfiddle.net/ySjqh/2/ )

The code works in theory to divide the page evenly into segments from 0-180, then calculates which segment the mouse appears in. Then uses the Math.sin() function to derive how much opacity to apply, based on a padded starting point of 0.4 opacity (jQuery style), and *should* use the mouse position to determine how much of the remaining 0.6 to apply based on its distance from center,  where mouse at center-page *should* yield full opacity.

What I don't get is why the script behaves this way, rolling through an entire sine wave when I've limited the input to the Math.sin(x) function to 1 < x < 180. If you replace xCoord with axis in the place where I build the jQuery text for #showme,  you'll see that it throws negative numbers- which shouldn't be happening! ... so I don't get what the problem/behavior results from!!! Frustrating!!!

Comment: Why are you using `sin`? Why don't you simply calculate the distance?

Comment: Looks like this has been answered here before- answer is Radians are used in JS not Degrees. Duh.

Comment: @Cristy - because Sin matches my desire to curve opacity at center and removes need for easing. It's just a logical fit, and I prefer handmade functions

Comment: code updated at JSfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
xCoord = (xCoord * Math.PI) / 180;  // Convert value to Radians
```

and it works..

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jUKVy/1/)**

Comment: Thanks- hey I am going to approximate PI at 3.15 because using static # performs better in this case- performance being the same reason I like to use handmade functions instead of tools like easing when possible...

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ySjqh/4/

```
axis = 0.6 * (1 - Math.abs(e.pageX - winW/2)/(winW/2));
```

Using the X distance from the center instead of `sin`.

Comment: I'm voting this up 1 for merit, and it's "handmade". But it still doesn't solve the problem of why the function behaves poorly. See my updated answer. Rads vs. Degrees is the solution. Thanks though :)

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the 'fiddle, I checked it out & I like the linear response actually. I have used Sine waves for many animation features so it's just comfortable for me, and performs fast compared to other premade functions.